# Named Pipe communication between service and application

Tags: c, windows

So I have a service which starts at boot time, and I have an application which I have placed in the startup folder.

So the client sometimes connects very late to the server of the named pipe.

Here is my code in my service.

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\popupPipe"),
                    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
                    PIPE_WAIT,
                    1, 1024 * 16, 1024 * 16,
                    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                    NULL);

HRESULT
SendMessage(){
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE) {   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
        WriteFile(hPipe, (char *)message->buffer, sizeof(message->buffer), &dwWritten, NULL);
        return S_OK;
    }
    return E_FAIL;
}
```

and here is the application

```
hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\popupPipe"),
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    0,
                    NULL);

if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return -1;

while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwRead;
    char buffer[100] = { 0 };
    while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE);
    if (dwRead == sizeof(buffer)) {
        dwRead = 0;
        buffer[100] = '\0';
        temp = &buffer[1];
        DisplayPopup(hInstance, cmdShow);
    }
}
return 0;
```

but at the clients end the application always returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

In the service `SendMessage` is called multiple times so even if it fails the first times it should succeed when the client connects shouldn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't check if the creation of the pipe suceeds. Looking at the Microsoft documentation, it probably does not succeed because you mix parameters:

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\popupPipe"),
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
                PIPE_WAIT,
                1, 1024 * 16, 1024 * 16,
                NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                NULL);
```

should be:

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\popupPipe"),
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,              // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
                PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                1, 1024 * 16, 1024 * 16,
                NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you, Just one more question. Does it matter that the client connects later?

Comment: If the pipe doesn't exist, then I think the client cannot connect. There is no pipe afterall. So the client _must_ connect later.

Comment: So the application which starts first should execute `CreateNamedPipe` and then the client which connects `CreateFile` correct?

Comment: @qwn - yes, `CreateFile` fail if name not exist. so `CreateNamedPipe` must be called *before* `CreateFile`. however client can use `WaitNamedPipe` - *Waits until either a time-out interval elapses or an instance of the specified named pipe is available for connection*

Comment: The FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE comment should still be part of the OpenMode parameter, not the PipeMode.  In other words, the comment should still be on the PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX line.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea